# How to get last two Sales' (by date) Product and Customer details from two separate tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables 1 is Products Table

[image: The Products Table]

Another is the Sales Table

[image: The Sales Table]

The sales table have dates in them, I want to get the last two purchase of each product with it's (ProductName, ProductID, Qty, CustName, CustID) ordered by date and I don't know how to go about doing that.

I tried using `union` but I can't limit it to last two orders of each product (or the products that has been purchased).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical solution is row_number():

```
select P.ProductId, ProductName, CustId, CustName, Date
from Products P
left join (
  select CustId, CustName, ProductId, Date,
         row_number() over (partition by ProductId 
                            order by Date desc, CustId desc) as rn 
  from Sales) LastSales
  on P.ProductId = LastSales.ProductId and LastSales.rn <= 2
```

In case there are several rows sold exactly at the same time above query returns only two of them. If you want to show all use rank() instead of row_number():

```
rank() over (partition by ProductId order by Date desc)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/P3IhT_OE)